# convert jenkins job name to WorkflowMultiBrancProject

Tags: java, jenkins

How do I get WorkflowMultiBrancProject object from jenkins job name (string) using java.

Thanks,
LifeIsButifool

Answer (score 0):

```
Jenkins.instance.getItem("test-job")
```

could work (untested).